# Scroll bar & Formatting in gantt chart using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, gantt-chart, ggplotly

I am trying to plot a gantt chart and have created it successfully, but being too many values involved, it is visually not presentable.[image: The Chart]
What should i add to the below code to add a vertical scroll bar in the chart. Also, how can i assign customized colors to the bar & change the background & font.

```
df <- read.csv("C:/Users/XXXX/Downloads/XXXX.csv" , stringsAsFactors = F)
df$Timeline.Start <- as.Date(df$Timeline.Start, format = "%m/%d/%Y")
df$Timeline.End <- as.Date(df$Timeline.End, format = "%m/%d/%Y")
df$System.Lease.ID <- as.character(df$System.Lease.ID)

ggplot(df, aes(colour= Timeline.Type, group = System.Lease.ID))  +
      geom_segment(aes(x=Timeline.Start, xend=Timeline.End, y=System.Lease.ID, yend=System.Lease.ID), size=3) +
      labs(x="Timeline.Start", y="System.Lease.ID", title="Project timeline")
```

Comment: Did you find a solution for this problem? I am facing the very same issue and I can't figure out what to do to scroll through gantt chart...

Comment: Unfortunately not yet,